# Real world uses of memcached for a website

Tags: mysql, performance, caching, memcached

I am trying to implement memcached into my website.

I have an image gallery where images are rarely changed (deleted etc). They are kept in a database.

now I know I could cache the result set returned by mysql, and from there every time a request to view the gallery is made it checks the cache to see if it exists, and serves it up instead of hitting the database again and again.

My question is, how is using memcached like this better than mysql's query cache, since both serve from memory?

Also, would storing the html string for things like a website header and footer in memcached give some slight performance increase? As I assume this would mean the server doesn't need to load the data from disk.

Comment: I would prefer memcache, and I would put header and footer if you can, of course without measures it is hard to take a decision. To increase further use nginx or cherokee instead of apache.

Comment: If you downvote please have the sack to leave a comment on why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL Query Cache has two big limitations when it comes to using it as an effective object level caching system.

1. The cache for a table is invalidated whenever the table is updated (e.g. UPDATE, INSERT or DELETE).
2. Query Cache cannot exist across different instances so if you are running around this scale Query Cache offers little benefit.

Another point of note (that might be obvious to some) is that the query cache only caches the results of deterministic queries - using date functions or anything similar will result in there always being a database hit.

IMO, the main use case of Memcached is that it offers memory object caching that will scale with your application. The fact that is also so simple to deploy makes it wonderful to deploy as a cache for your data layer.

In your specific case it does not seem to warrant the use of memcached, as you specify that your data does not change much; and it does not seem to me that there is scope for it scaling beyond using more than one db server.

For a far more thorough list of limitations and characteristics of MySQL query Cache [check this out](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/07/27/mysql-query-cache/).